# What does an Invisible Stalker do if not given a command by its summoner?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, summoning

In Storm kings thunder, there is a part where

> the PCs are in Zephyros' (a cloud giant) tower and some howling hatred cultists come and visit asking for his help.

One of the people has a "smiling bag" which is actually a bag of holding that contains an Invisible Stalker.

What I'm trying to figure out is how the Invisible Stalker's summoning and command mechanics work. In the encounter, during the cultists' first turn of combat he "releases the stalker and commands it to **attack the cult's enemies**"

Now, if the person holding the bag (who we assume is the one who summoned the stalker) was unable to command it, would the stalker simply be inert since it has no given commands? The page on invisible stalkers says the following-

> **Directed Hunter** When an invisible stalker is created, it stays at its summoner's side until it is given a task to perform.

So if it had no task, would it simply not do anything? I know that if the summoner died AFTER the command was given, the stalker would still carry out the command but I'm very uncertain about what happens if no command is given but the stalker is released from the bag - could someone other than the summoner give the stalker commands?

Also since the bag containing the stalker is a bag of holding, if the bag were pierced or destroyed in someway, would the stalker die? Or would it just pop out of the bag? Do the mechanics of a bag of holding allow things inside to push outwards, making it visible (from outside) that something is in the bag?

Comment: I've edited your question to A: hide the spoilers (I was kind of bummed by it myself) and B: change the title to something that suits A and focuses more on your question. If you're dissatisfied with the edit, you can roll it back on the edit page or edit it more yourself.

Comment: Oh cool thanks, and suuuper sorry about the spoilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the book implies that the cultist is the summoner because **Invisible Stalkers cannot take orders other than finding object or hunting down someone without vanishing afterwards (MM 192)**. This would make chaining command impossible. The description of the Stalker in the monster manual states that he is bound and follows the summoner and is otherwise dormant until commanded. The Stalker would be inert until he is pulled out and commanded.

The only reason I can assume this is a problem is if the summoner was killed beforehand. In this case refer to the Monster Manual: "If the summoner dies in the interim, the invisible stalker vanishes after completing it's task." Having no task to complete it would just vanish.

As to how the creature actually got in the bag, I assume it was pushed in without a command, because if it was ordered it would vanish after completing the order.

Comment: Now to make a magic box with a button that summons Invisible Stalkers who shout "I'm Mister Meseeks, Look at me!" when summoned.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a problem with just assuming that the summoner gave just one command: "Obey these guys"? This would solve all your chain of command problems.

If the bag is pierced the stalker comes out: but not here. The description says "it's contents are scattered on the Astral Plane."

Comment: The encounter in the book specifically states that the cultist opens the bag and gives the command "attack the cult's enemies" so the assumption being made here is that the stalker was summoned and placed into the bag with no previous commands given, however i guess its possible that the stalker could be commanded by mutliple people with your assumption being made.